# Tomorite dilution

Tags: fertilizer

The bottle of Tomorite says 20ml should be diluted into 4.5L of water for use on 2 plants.

4.5L of water for 2 plants is more than I'd usually give.

Would it be OK to quadruple the dose but also quadruple the number of plants?

E.g. instead of 20ml in 4.5L for 2 plants, use 80ml in 4.5 litres for **8** plants.

Therefore each plant would get about 0.6 litres of 'fertilised' water rather than 2.25L, but the water would have a higher concentration of Tomorite.

Thanks.

Comment: A higher concentration could "burn" the plant (leaves, stems, and/or roots) on contact.  FWIW a single fully grown tomato plant may need 4.5L of water *per day* in a hot climate.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, the ratio of the feed to water should remain the same, so you can either use half the amount of water and half the amount of measured feed suggested, or twice the amount in twice as much water and so on. For instance, I actually only have two tomato plants in pots, which at this time, means 4.5 litres of mixed feed is too much, so I use the feed in 1.5 litres of water, which I worked out to be roughly just over 5ml. Shortly, I will need to mix it up in 3 litres of water each time as the water requirement increases with growth, and will work out the appropriate ratio of feed to quantity of water.